# what I have to do to complete this Dynamic Programming problem?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a homework that tells this:
A hawker has to decide what products to take on his next trip. Unfortunately, you have a weight limit that you can carry, and having this in mind, you have to choose the best combination of products with at most this weight that will allow you to have maximum revenue.

You will receive the weight limit that the seller can carry, followed by a list of products from which he can choose (assume you have an unlimited stock of each product at your disposal). For each product will be listed its name, its value, and its weight. You should print the maximum revenue you can get if you sell all the products you choose to carry, followed by the list of products you should take to get that revenue (including replicates, if appropriate), sorted alphabetically. If there are 2 products with the same profitability / weight should give priority to the products that appear first in the entry list.

I am reading the input from a file.

> **Input:**
>   14
>   bible 20 2
>   microwave 150 10
>   television 200 15
>   toaster 40 3
>
> **Output:**
>  190
>  bible
>  bible
>  microwave

I have made this code to reach the maximum value the hawker can carry with him:

```py
import sys


def knapsack(list_values,list_weight,limit_weight,n):
    matrix = [[0 for x in range(limit_weight+1)] for y in range (n+1)]
    res = []
    for i in range(n+1):
        for j in range(limit_weight+1):
            if i == 0 or j == 0:
                matrix[i][j] = 0
            elif list_weight[i-1]<= j:
                matrix[i][j] = max(list_values[i-1] + matrix[i-1][j-list_weight[i-1]], matrix[i-1][j])
            else:
                matrix[i][j] = matrix[i-1][j]

    return matrix[n][limit_weight], matrix


def main():

    txt = sys.stdin.readlines()
    limit_weight = int(txt[0])
    list_names = []
    list_values = []
    list_weight = []
    picked = []

    for lines in txt[1:]:
        lines = lines.split()
        list_weight.append(int(lines[2]))
        list_values.append(int(lines[1]))
        list_names.append(lines[0])

    result, matrix = knapsack(list_values,list_weight, limit_weight, len(list_values))
    print(result)


main()
```

I can not figure out which items are chosen.
Can you help me?

Comment: can you please [edit] the question and clearly show the input and expected output? are you reading the input from a file, or getting user input from the keyboard?

Comment: I have already edited like you said. I add to the question that I am reading the input from a file.

Comment: I put in console python3 nameOfFile.py < nameOfFile.txt